# How to connect Wireless Adapter to Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu Trusty 14.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, wifi

I am running Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. The image for the Ubuntu install can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi).

According to the image after installing linux-firmware it should be able to connect to the wifi. However the image is pretty bare and doesn't come with much. I installed wpa-supplicant and placed this code in the wpa-supplicant.conf file

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/ver/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="RECUV-VICON"
        scan_ssid=1
        psk="fluffyapple617"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP
        auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

And placed this code in /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-driver wext
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

When I do `ifup wlan0` followed by `ifdown wlan0` and another `ifup wlan0` it displays

```
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: wlan0  error: No such file or directory
```

There is a very similar thread that I found on this issue [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/add-wireless-adapter-to-raspberrypi). According to the solutions it just requires the correct driver for the adapter. Typing `lsusb` results in listing the device as such

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 148f:3572 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT3572 Wireless Adapter.
```

I searched for the exact linux drivers for Ralink wifi adapters and ended up [here](https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb).

I added the components to my sources.list and it didn't install right away because several of the files conflict with the initial linux firmware so I needed to force override them. However it properly installed afterwards.

I know that the wifi adapter works, works with ubuntu, and works with the Pi itself. I tested it on my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 trusty and it was able to connect. I also tried the Ubuntu Mate image on the Pi and the wifi adapter was also able to connect.

What am I missing or is there another error preventing this?